# Getting Error after upgrading php version 5.3.0 to 5.3.2 using Wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Wamp giving error when i have started it and press the online or any other option. I have setup all of the option to upgrade php version but after setup these i have getting this error and older version is working fine.

window[image]

Comment: if i suggest you to use php 5.4+ ??

Comment: hi,abdulla! but what"s the problem with 5.3.2?